# Get fields that are datetime from sql server

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, validation, sqldatatypes

I have the following table `User` in my database

```
Name(Varchar)  | DateOfBirth(datetime)     | Age(int)
======================================================
John           |      2014-12-20 23:59:59  |  0
Mary           |      2014-12-20 23:59:59  |  1
```

How can I verify through javascript if the field `DateOfBirth` of the table `User` of the database `z` is of type `datetime`?

Comment: Why javascript? It's not a technology you usually associate with SQL Server.

Comment: you should do it on your Application Layer

Comment: And why do you need to validate the data type? Your schema is fixed so you already know what type it is. Some context to the problem might get you better answers.

Comment: But....you said that you have a table with a column `DateOfBirth` of datetime datatype, why do you need to verify it with javascript?

Comment: I have to verify with javascript because i have to get the data that is in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and set it to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss Lamak.

Comment: Changing the format doesn't have anything to do with verifying the data type. If the column is a `DATETIME` in your table, then it is a `DATETIME`, period

Comment: You don't set the format on datetime data. You set the format when you want to display it as a string. What exactly are you trying to do because you question and comments make no sense.

Comment: Something like jquery validation plugin but that can work with sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will verify the table metadata:

```
SELECT data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'User' 
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DateOfBirth'
```

data_type should be DATETIME.